# Ajax calls not populating the text field

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

Two Ajax calls. They both execute the calls but the first one returns a drop down values in the text input field and the second one with `extraParam` fails to show the drop down with the matching values in text input field. I have checked, the right values are returned from the Spring Controller. Any reason why this is not working? What the difference between both the calls other than passing an extra parameter?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( ".oid" ).autocomplete({
            source: "${pageContext. request. contextPath}/app/X.htm"
        });

    });


   $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#fifa" ).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/app/Y.htm',
                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                        extraParam: OneMoreParamValue
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log('response=', data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't call the response function, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source
Something like

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log('response=', data);
    response(data);
}
```

you might have to set the data type to 'json' as well.

Comment: JSON transformation is done by Spring-MVC. I was missing response(data)